# SQL Server: How to check if a windows user exists in the database but under a different user name

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I am trying to create a user via a T-SQL script in SQL Server 2005/2008. I run the following SQL to check if the user exists and create the user if it does not:

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * 
               FROM   sys.database_principals 
               WHERE  name = N'MyDomain\MyUser') 
  BEGIN 
      CREATE USER [MyDomain\MyUser] FOR LOGIN [MyDomain\MyUser] WITH default_schema=[dbo]; 

      SELECT 1; 
  END 
ELSE 
  BEGIN 
      SELECT 0; 
  END
```

Unfortunately, this does not work when the windows account **MyDomain\MyUser** is already in the database but under a different name. An example of this would be if **MyDomain\MyUser** was the account that created the database then it will already be in the database under the dbo user. When this is the case I get the following error:

> Msg 15063, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   The login already has an account under
>   a different user name.

How can I check if the windows user **MyDomain\MyUser** is already a user in the database even if it is under a different user name?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Do the testing for windows user vs sys.database_principals using the SID rather than the name/user_id:

```
select * from sys.database_principals where sid = SUSER_SID(N'MyDomain\MyUser')
```

Since this uses the SID of the login ID, it doesn't matter what name it was mapped to in the database.

Comment: i needed to select from `sys.syslogins` instead, +1 for `SUSER_SID`